# Android Epresso: DatePicker Click on OK add a year instead of validate

Tags: android, datepicker, android-espresso

In an Google Espresso test, I'm trying to click on the OK button of a DatePickerDialog.

But instead of validating my input, it just add a year and does not close the dialog.

It seems that the click is done on the "+" button of year's column. Is that an Espresso bug or am I missing something?

Here is my Espresso code (in Kotlin):

```
onView(allOf(iz(instanceOf(javaClass<Button>())), withText("OK"),
            isDisplayed()) as Matcher<View>).perform(click())
```

Comment: I still have the issue today, and it happens only on Android 4.x with the spinner datePicker, the calendar view works just fine. It is like the click happens just a pixel above the Ok button and then hit the spinner's year column :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading my testing device to 4.4.4, the bug has gone by itself: it was an Android < 4.4 bug T_T

Answer (score 9):

It's probably not perfect (because I hardcode the text "OK"), but I manage to do it in my tests using this snippet:

```
// Change the date of the DatePicker. Don't use "withId" as at runtime Android shares the DatePicker id between several sub-elements
onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(DatePicker.class.getName()))).perform(PickerActions.setDate(1989, 8, 25));
// Click on the "OK" button to confirm and close the dialog
onView(withText("OK")).perform(click());
```

Comment: I already did that in my posted code (with more condition to try to narrow it down to the button) and it does not work. My problem is not setting the date, it is clicking on "OK" makes the DatePicker add one year instead of clicking the button.

Comment: My point was that it works perfectly fine for me (with just the 2 lines of code I posted above), and doesn't add a year to the result. So the problem may be in your code (maybe somewhere you add an onClickListener and you have a conflict on IDs or on the listeners). But with just the code you posted, there's nothing else we can do for you, I'm afraid. Either you post all your code, or you create a new empty activity with just a DatePicker to test. If it works, it means you added something wrong along the way in your code.

Comment: The code worked locally for me, but in firebase testlab, it could not find view with "OK", even though in video playback, the OK button was showing at time of exception.

Answer (score 5):

On some versions of Android "OK" on DatePickerDialog is replaced with "Set" or "Done".
Try:

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
```

This will click on dialog's positive button. No matter how it is called.

Comment: No luck, it adds one year to the DatePickerDialog :/

Answer (score 4):

For those who have issues clicking the `OK` button, I would suggest the following code:

```
onView(
    anyOf(
        withText(android.R.string.ok),
        withId(android.R.id.button1)
    )
)
    .inRoot(isDialog())
    .perform(click())
```

1. By using `android.R.string.ok` you cover all possible versions of the `"ok"` text, regardless of the current Locale and Android version. It is even recommended (lint warning) by Android Studio when ever there is a need for the `"ok"` text.
2. Thanks to `anyOf`, you can add more than one `ViewMatcher` to make sure you can cover all known possibilities. So should you stumble into a new way to access the "OK button", you can just add it in the `anyOf`.
3. Finally, I would wager that adding `.inRoot(isDialog())` check is a good way to make sure you target a `Dialog`. Should the `DatePickerDialog` not be on-screen, this will definitely fail! And for a good reason.